# How do you get whether a column is a primary key of a table from with all columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting all the columns of all tables listed down of my data base with following query in mySQL

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position
```

I want to get all columns whether it's a primary key or not? For primary key columns to appear as y and non primary key columns to appear as n in this query. How can I achieve that with this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COLUMN_KEY` column and `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT column_name, CASE WHEN COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI' THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END AS result
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
   AND `table_name` = 'tab'     -- table name
ORDER BY `table_name`, ordinal_position
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a7a8/5/0)**</kbd>